# saveAs dose not work in HuaWei Mobile browser，Chrome&Safari is OK

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I want to download the BLob file stream that comes back from the background，Chrome&Safari is OK，only HuaWei Mobile browser&under IOS10 which is not supported . I tried everything but nothing.
Ask a master for help.

detail in https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/617

`code`
    import FileSaver,{saveAs} from 'file-saver'

```
myPromise.then(data=>{
    let blob = new Blob([(data)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'fileName.pdf')
})
```